# how to install Drupal 8 Librabries API module

Tags: drupal, libraries

I have downloaded the Libraries API https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries from here.. put in the Libraries folder under on the root

so it looks like this /libraries/libraries but it does not show up on the extend page for installation. the same thing with nivo slider put it under /modules/nivo_slider and still can see it so that i can install... Please help.

Im running drupal 8.1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries API is a module, so you should put it in the /modules directory in order to see it on the Extend page